# Questions on orthogonal projections on a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

> Let $u= \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $S = \left\{\frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}, \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} \right\}$.
>
> 1. Find the unique vectors $w \in W$ and $z \in W^\perp$, such that $z = u - w$.
> 2. Find the orthogonal projection of $u$ on $W$.
> 3. Verify that $z$ is in $W^\perp$.

This is what I have so far:

1. $w = (u \cdot v_1)v_1 + (u \cdot v_2)v_2 = (3/3)v_1 + (3/3)v_2$, and after plugging in the vectors, I got $w = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -3 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, thus $z = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.
2. projection of $u$ on $W$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
3. **When I tried verifying that $z$ is in $W^\perp$, I was not getting $0$, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.**

Comment: SORRY, I'm fairly new on this site so I don't know how to insert vectors.

Comment: Are you sure that you’ve stated the problem correctly? If $z=u-w$ and $z$ and $w$ are both in $W$, then so must be $u$, but it’s not.

Comment: @AmR regarding the formatting, here is a link to the MathJax tutorial, it will help you https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Projection of $u$ on $W$ is $w$, not $z$. And what you get for $w$ should be $(1,-1,0)$ – you forgot to divide by the three.

Comment: Anything to say, AmR?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you're right I forgot to divide by the 3. So w=[1 -1 0] and z=[2 2 1]

Comment: Good. But if you intend to continue to use this website, please follow the suggestion above regarding the MathJax tutorial.

Comment: I don't see in your post any explanation saying what is $W$, but I assume it is the span of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w=(u\cdot v_1)v_1+(u\cdot v_2)v_2=(3/3)v_1+(3/3)v_2$

After plugging in the vectors and simplifying I got $w=(1,-1,0)$, thus $z=(2,2,1)$.

Projection of $u$ on $W$ is $(2,2,1)$.

$z\cdot v_1=4-2-2=0$

$z\cdot v_2=2-4+2=0$